A $2$-covector $\omega$ is non-degenerate if and only if $(\omega_{ij})$ is non-singular
The following is from Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds:

Exercise 22.1. Show that the following are equivalent for $2$-covector $\omega$ on a finite dimensional vector space $V$:

$\omega$ is nondegenerate [defined as $\widehat{\omega} := v\lrcorner \omega$ is invertible].
For each nonzero $v\in V$, there exists $w\in V$ such that $\omega(v,w) \neq 0$.
In terms of some (hence every) basis, the matrix $(\omega_{ij})$ representing $\omega$ is nonsingular.


Shouldn't the third characterization deal with $\widehat{\omega}$ as opposed to $\omega$ itself? I checked the errata and there is nothing about this, so I wonder if I'm missing something. What is the meaning of $(\omega_{ij})$?

Remember, the matrix $(\omega_{ij})$ satisfies $\omega(v,w) = \sum_{i,j} v^i \omega_{ij} w^j$ for all vectors $v$ and $w$. What does this tell you about the matrix representation of $\widehat{\omega}$?
